# ESP32-CAM does not appear on COM ports in Windows or on /dev/tty* in Linux

Tags: camera, esp32, usbserial

I have bought an ESP32-CAM module and I connected the module to my Ubuntu device via a USB-TTL converter. Although it probably is not relevant, I want to use ESP-IDF extension on VSCode to flash some program on the CAM device. I followed the steps many online walk-through tutorials show. However, I cannot see the device, since there are no devices on the `ls -l /dev/tty*` output list.

I tried to test my device by using a Windows machine. In the Windows 10 machine I can see the device on my device manager under Other Devices as "USB Serial". I expected to see a COM port but I do not usually use ESP-IDF on Windows so I might be doing something wrong.
Then, I tried to connect the device to RaspberryPi 3, on which I saw the /dev/tty0 appear. However, I did neither have VSCode nor ESP-IDF framework on the machine so I could not try to flash the CAM device.
I bought a second ESP32-CAM to ensure that the first one was not broken. This one has an integrated USB-TTL converter board stuck under it. This CAM device also returns similar results.

I have other ESP32 devices with whom I had no trouble connecting in the past on my Ubuntu machine. Am I missing something? Is there a different method to ESP32-CAM?

If there is any additional information I should provide, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this even works. But while searching the issue, I have came across this solution, which worked for Ubuntu:

```
systemctl stop brltty-udev.service
sudo systemctl mask brltty-udev.service
systemctl stop brltty.service
systemctl disable brltty.service
```